# how to check if a channel name starts with a certain string discord.py

Tags: discord.py

```py
@client.command()
async def delete(ctx):
    channel = discord.utils.get(ctx.channel.startswith("Ticket"))
    await ctx.channel.delete()
```

as stated in the title, how do i check if a channel starts with the string "Ticket", not if its named ticket, im trying to make a ticket system, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can loop through all [text_channels](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=text_channels#discord.Guild.text_channels) and then compare the [TextChannel.name](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=channel%20name#discord.TextChannel.name) with what you want.

It will be a sting so you can use `startswith` or `=='Name'` if you want an exact match.

It is better to send a message there in testing instead of deleting it.

```py
@client.command()
async def delete(ctx):
    for channel in ctx.guild.text_channels:
        if channel.name.startswith('Ticket'):
            await channel.send('Deleting.....')
            #await channel.delete()
```